# WSO2 CEP Extension ML with Collaborative Filtering

Tags: collaborative-filtering, wso2-cep, wso2-ml

It's possibile to integrate a Collaborative Filtering Explicit Data model generated with WSO2 Machine Learner module? I want to query model with Siddhi, but in WSO2 docs i not found any way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The current released versions of WSO2 Machine Learner (1.0.0 and 1.1.0) do not provide support for collaborative filtering as a CEP extension, therefore you cannot use collaborative filtering models created with Machine Learner with a Siddhi query.
At the moment, only models created for numerical prediction, classification, anomaly detection and deep learning can be used with a Siddhi query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to integrate machine learning models with WSO2 CEP and use Siddhi to get the predictions. Please use this [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Predictive+Analytics+with+WSO2+Machine+Learner).

Tishan

Answer (score 0):

Not only collaborative filtering algorithm, any machine learning model you developed using WSO2 Machine Learning Server can be easily integrated with other products in the WSO2 echo system. For instance, you can integrate WSO2 ML models easily with WSO2 ESB using a special mediator called predict mediator [1]. Also, we have written an extension for the WSO2 CEP Server [2] as well. In addition to that, we are planning to add few more extensions in upcoming releases.

Sometimes, you might want to install machine learning models built using WSO2 ML Server outside of  the WSO2 echo system. For this purpose, we have provided two options namely Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML) and pure Java serialized object support.

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML110/Predict+Mediator+for+WSO2+ESB

[2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML110/WSO2+CEP+Extension+for+ML+Predictions